# Solr diffrence between analysis results and indexed values

Tags: solr

I want to use transformations by replacements on my extracted/indexed values of few copied fields with Solr.

In my schema.xml, I have the *source_file* field who contains a value. I copy this value into the *collection* field. Then I use PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory (regex / replacement) to modify this value as I want :

```
<field name="source_file" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" docValues="false"/>

<field name="collection" type="collectionType" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

<copyField source="source_file" dest="collection"/>

<fieldType name="collectionType" class="solr.TextField" stored="true" indexed="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="A" replacement="B"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
     <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="A" replacement="B"/>
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**EDIT 1**

In Solr webapp, when I use the Analysis interface, I see that the pattern replacement works for Index & Query forms.
My *source_file* value is modified by the setted value. Which means that the definition of my schema seems correct. A becomes B.

But, when I use a Solr Query, I see that the pattern replacement not works. No change is taken into account (I always have the value A).

http://xxx:898x/solr/discovery_collection/select?fl=collection&indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json

The result shows that the value of *collection* field is not modify by the replacement pattern when I use a query.

I've done all my configurations into schema.xml. Nothing into solrconfig.xml.
Would I have forgotten a configuration (into solrconfig.xml ?) to force the indexing of modified fields?

**EDIT 2**

My request handlers in solrconf.xml :

```
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">10</int>
           <str name="df">text</str>
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
           <str name="timeAllowed">30000</str>
      <bool name="preferLocalShards">false</bool>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
           <int name="rows">10</int>
           <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="timeAllowed">30000</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>

      <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

**EDIT 3**

I've just seen that it works. But in fact the value "B" is stored/indexed and I can search it by query, but the value "B" is not displayed in the json result of the query (it displays the value "A").

Do have I to use custuom updateRequestProcessorChain and requestHandler in solrconfig.xml? And add a custom class in lib/ to do the pattern transformation?

Comment: Do you test it at both Query and Index sections of Solr?

Comment: This is very vague : " But, when I verify indexed values, with the "Query" interface, I see that the pattern replacement not works. No change is taken into account."

Query interface ? you mean running a query ? Can you show your config for your request handler ?

What does not work ? the stored content is not meant to change. 
You are not able to find what you want ? you should check the indexed content ( schema browser is your best bet here or Luke)

Comment: Thx. I've just edit my initial post to improve description of my problem. I hope it could be better for you to help me.

Comment: Which one requestHandler should I use? update? query? with which parameters?

Comment: I've just seen that it works. But in fact the value "B" is stored/indexed and I can search it by query, but the value "B" is not displayed in the json result of the query (it displays the value "A").

Do have I to use custuom updateRequestProcessorChain and requestHandler in solrconfig.xml? And add a custom class in lib/ to do the pattern transformation?